# How to mtd_dataflash.c with spi protocal ..?

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux, cortex-m, uclinux

I have configure for spi_gpio driver and its working fine as in this link [Spidev do not write/read simultaneously using ioctl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895338/spidev-do-not-write-read-simultaneously-using-ioctl), I came to know that the spi protocol is working fine, now I want use that spi protocol to communicate with AT45DB321D 4M seria flash. I found mtd_dataflash.c is same as my device by looking at the data-sheet of AT45DB321D.

Is the way I am gong is correct...?

If so how can I map this driver with spi to communicate with AT45DB321D serial flash...? guide me to solve this by providing useful docs are suggestion.

(I am using cortex-m3 LPC1788 development bard with uclinux)

**EDITED:** I am able to read the device ID by the following code  and using /dev/spidev0.1

```
int ret = 0;
int fd;
unsigned char buff[10],buf[]={ 0x9F }, str[4];
ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
if (ret == -1)
    pabort("can't set bits per word");

ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
if (ret == -1)
    pabort("can't get bits per word");

/*
 * max speed hz
 */
ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
if (ret == -1)
    pabort("can't set max speed hz");

ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
if (ret == -1)
    pabort("can't get max speed hz");
write(fd,buf,1);
read(fd, buff,10);
LPC178X_CS_HIGH;
sprintf(str,"%02X%02X%02X\n",buff[0],buff[1],buff[2]);
printf("Devce ID: ");
puts(str);
```

my question is how can I write a data in to flash AT45DB321D memory please any help...?

Answer (score 0):

Useful docs and suggestions always come from the kernel sources. Read how SPI framework work and look what other developer did. For example, you can see how [Atmel 9260](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-at91/board-sam9260ek.c) register the **mtd_dataflash**. The modalias field is used by the bus infrastructore to match the device with the driver. The other fields are specific of your hardware.